# Своя реализация XMPP протокола

Tags: c#, xmpp

День добрый. Пишу в качестве курсовика Jabber клиента.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
У бота в контактах только мой JID, когда я захожу с одного рабочего места, все нормально.
Если захожу с двух ресурсов (дома и на рабочем компьютере), боту 10-20 раз в секунду начинают бесконечные приходить сообщения Presence (статус дом = онлайн, статус работа = онлайн), причем некоторые сообщения приходят "оборванными" с продолжением в следующем сетевом пакете. Это я починил, хотя и непонятно почему так.

Вопрос - почему так много сообщений о статусе?

Comment: > причем некоторые сообщения приходят "оборванными" с продолжением в следующем сетевом пакете. 


в следующем tcp пакете? или как то по другому?

Comment: Видимо да.
бесконечный цикл: 
1. прочитать все из потока
2. попытаться пропарсить прочитанное как xml
3. при ошибке парсинга ждать еще информацию в потоке.

Comment: данные в tcp пакетах могут читаться не такими блоками, как пишутся. То есть, если Вы записали в два прихода (1 2 3 4 5) (6 7 8 9 10), то прочитаться может как (1 2 3) (4 5 6 7 8) (9 10) и это абсолютно нормально и штатно. Но вот прочитаться как (6 7 8 9 10) (1 2 3 4 5) может только в случае конкретных проблем операционной системы (но такого в современных системах обычно не бывает).

Система гарантирует порядок, но не гарантирует разбивку для tcp.  В случае udp все наоборот. Гарантируется размер, но не порядок (даже сам факт доставки не гарантируется).